# How to select value from array by key

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have such array in my `class`:

```
   stuff = [
        { ['xwz']: 'https://site1.com' },
        { ['erx']: 'https://site2.com' },
        { ['qwery']: 'https://someurl-here.com' },
        { ['stuff']: 'http://morestuffhere.com' }
    ]
```

I want to get the value(`'https://...'`) by passing the key like `this.stuff['xwz']` but didn't work this way. Any ideas?

Comment: That creates an *array* of 4 items, each a dictionary (aka "plain object") with single (and different) keys. `stuff[0]['xwz']` would "work". However, it'd probably be better to choose a uniform key or to use a dictionary instead of an array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
// declare as
stuff = {
    'xwz': 'https://site1.com',
    'erx': 'https://site2.com',
    'qwery': 'https://someurl-here.com',
    'stuff': 'http://morestuffhere.com'
 }

// Access with
this.stuff['xwz'] // returns 'https://site1.com'
```

Comment: why use `this` to access `stuff`?

Comment: @shusson he was right btw :). I need to put `this.` otherwise I can't access the `stuff` in my `class`

Comment: @sreginogemoh makes sense, then can you update your question to reflect that `stuff` is a member of a class? nvm you already did that :)

Answer (score -1):

So the way you have written your code you need to access the array index first and then the object... like this (assuming you are using a class property)

```
this.stuff[0].xwz // This will retrieve the first array element
```

Now, why you are not using just an object for this task, like this

```
 stuff = {
    xwz: 'https://site1.com',
    erx: 'https://site2.com',
    qwery: 'https://someurl-here.com',
    stuff: 'http://morestuffhere.com'
 }

    this.stuff.xwz
```

Comment: why use `this` to access `stuff`?

Comment: because is typescript, and we are assuming that `stuff` is an instance property (like a global variable inside of a class, `this` refers to the class itself... is like saying the `stuff` property of `this` class)

Comment: that is a bad assumption, the example makes no implication what scope it is in. In JavaScript and thus in TypeScript, `this` may not even refer to a class, it could be window object. Read more about `this` on the TypeScript handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this or  http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: that is not correct. The fact that the user asked like this ```stuff = [] ``` (without the keyword var or let, implies that is a class property...) please check this link and see the property `greetings` http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: From the official Typescript site `You’ll notice that in the class when we refer to one of the members of the class we prepend this.. This denotes that it’s a member access.`... so the assumption is far from far fetched

Comment: I understand the confusion but rather than assume, we should improve the answer so that there are no ambiguities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134443/discussion-between-shusson-and-pato-salazar).

Comment: Finally stuff = [], using no var or let and using equals sign hints a class property in typescript.